# Using Python: How to divide two different indicators (amount and exchange rate) in case two attributes match (Country AND date)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-manipulation

I downloaded and imported a csv file from an economics research database which contains three columns ([screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79mxs.png)): "Country-Code", "Time", "Indicator". There are basically two types of indicators (1. amount in local currency and 2. EUR exchange rate). How can I create a new column "EUR_amount" in Python that divdes the amount with the rate in case the countrycode and the month is the same for both items, e.g. EUR = amount/rate where country and time matches?

Any help highly appreciated! (Please keep in mind that I am quite a noob with python and this is my first question on stackoverflow ever.) Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit: Adding this code after receiving feedback from [mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) (thanks for that):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'country_code':['EU','UK','US','EU','UK','US','EU','UK','US','EU','UK','US','EU','UK','US','EU','UK','US'],
               'date':['2019-03','2019-03','2019-03','2019-04','2019-04','2019-04','2019-05','2019-05','2019-05','2019-03','2019-03','2019-03','2019-04','2019-04','2019-04','2019-05','2019-05','2019-05'],
              'item':['exposure','exposure','exposure','exposure','exposure','exposure','exposure','exposure','exposure','FX-rate','FX-rate','FX-rate','FX-rate','FX-rate','FX-rate','FX-rate','FX-rate','FX-rate'],
              'value':[15000,9000,13000,16500,8750,17000,17000,7999,25000,1.00,1.25,0.90,1,1.23,0.93,1.00,1.24,0.95]})
print(df)
```

So, to restate my question: How can I divide the item exposure with the item FX-rate under the condition of country_code AND date are matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first split the data frames into two parts - exposure and FX-rate

```
fx = df[df["item"]=="FX-rate"]
exp = df[df["item"]!="FX-rate"]
```

After that, you can use

```
merged_df = pd.merge(fx,exp,on=["country_code","date"],how='outer')
```

See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html for other arguments and examples.

The above will result in

| country_code | date | item_x | value_x | item_y | value_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EU | 2019-03 | FX-rate | 1.00 | exposure | 15000.0 |
| UK | 2019-03 | FX-rate | 1.25 | exposure | 9000.0 |
| US | 2019-03 | FX-rate | 0.90 | exposure | 13000.0 |
| EU | 2019-04 | FX-rate | 1.00 | exposure | 16500.0 |
| UK | 2019-04 | FX-rate | 1.23 | exposure | 8750.0 |
| US | 2019-04 | FX-rate | 0.93 | exposure | 17000.0 |
| EU | 2019-05 | FX-rate | 1.00 | exposure | 17000.0 |
| UK | 2019-05 | FX-rate | 1.24 | exposure | 7999.0 |
| US | 2019-05 | FX-rate | 0.95 | exposure | 25000.0 |

Next is just a matter of division

```
merged_df["Convert"] = merged_df["value_y"]/merged_df["value_x"]
```